# Is it possible to have multiple projects in a single VS Code workspace?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a Java project and I'm using VS Code with the Extensions for Java pack.  The project is essentially two separate applications. There's the app and there's its build tool.
They are both in the same repo and are essentially siblings, structure-wise.

```
/src/builder/java/xyz
/src/main/java/xyz
```

The problem is that they can have different, conflicting dependencies.
Can I edit the `settings.json` such that I can set a `java.project.referencedLibraries` for each application separately?

Comment: use a **Multi Root Workspace**

Comment: As far as I can, multi root workspaces are essentially the opposite of what I'm looking for.  I would like multiple settings.json files for the same root based on which folder I am in.  Mult-Root workspaces are establishing that disparate folders belong to the same project and settings.json configuration.

Comment: you have a separate settings.json per Workspace in the Multi Root Workspace

Comment: [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If appropriate for your use-case, use [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces). Each root workspace has its own `.vscode/settings` file, and settings can be applied to the whole multi-root workspace in its `.code-workspace` file.

It is currently not supported to have specific `settings.json` apply to specific subdirectories in regular workspaces. See the following issue tickets:

- [Monolithic structure, multiple project settings
  #32693](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32693)
- [Add ability to extend from other settings files #15909](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15909)

<sup><sub>[You can show your support for the feature-request by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>