# How to use launch config inside nested folder in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[This documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_debugging) on multi-root-workspaces in VS Code states

> VS Code searches across all folders for `launch.json` debug configuration files and displays them with the folder name as a suffix.

I only have one folder listed in a .code-workspace file. It is structured as follows

```
front-end/
├─ .vscode/
│  ├─ launch.json
├─ apps/
│  ├─ e2e/
│  │  ├─ .vscode/
│  │  │  ├─ launch.json
│  ├─ website/
│  │  ├─ .vscode/
│  │  │  ├─ launch.json
```

VS Code picks up only on debug configurations inside the top-level launch.json, but does not find the configurations in lower levels.

I'd like to be able to use the e2e debug configuration when I'm in a subfolder of e2e, and the website configuration when I'm in a subfolder of website. I don't want to add these folders to the workspace, as they are already showing up fine as subfolders of front-end.

How can I get the debug configurations of all the launch.json files to appear?

Comment: you only see `.vscode/launch.json` files that are in the root of a workspace

Comment: you need to setup the launch configs in the `front-end/.vscode/launch.json` to use the code in the `e2e` folder

Comment: you can always create a custom VSC, by modifying the source code and build an exe

Comment: possibly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75835225/11107541 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/75454597/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "folders" that are referred to in your quote are `root folders`, not subFolders under root folders.  The docs don't really make that clear, but the other mentions of "folders" in the same docs do seem to be talking about root folders only.  Like where it talks about adding folders.

And this from the debugging docs themselves:

> VS Code keeps debugging configuration information in a `launch.json`
> file located in a `.vscode` folder in your workspace (project root
> folder) or in your user settings or workspace settings.

From [Debugging: Launch Configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)

So there are only the 3 locations for launch configurations, not including subFolders.

See also [Github issue: Nested Launch Configurations](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7875) - closed and I don't believe ever considered elsewhere.