# Is there a way to specify recommended VS Code extensions for a subproject in a monorepo?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a monorepo with the following directory structure

```
 backend/
 frontend/
 .vscode/
   extensions.json
```

However, I would like to conditionally recommend an extension for the `frontend` project, when someone works on that.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

I have tried creating a `.vscode/extension.json` but VS Code doesn't seem to pick up that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no. I've worked on projects where I've wanted to do the same thing. Even if you use multi-root workspaces and recommend an extension in an individual root workspace's `.vscode/extensions.json` instead of in the `.code-workspace` file's `extensions` property, the recommendation appeared not to be treated as having any notion of being scoped to a particular root workspace. Add to that that how an extension behaves for multi-root workspaces is (to my limited knowledge) up to the extension. At the time of this writing, I don't think there's any notion of extension activation being scopable to a root workspace folder in a multi-root workspace.

In the multi-root workspace scenario, one option is to just not use extensions.json to recommend extensions and instead use your project's readme. Another option is to just use extensions.json and let the user decide which recommended extensions they want to install and enable. I personally use the second option. But in actuality, for the project where I used the multi-root workspace feature, it was mostly as a crutch for a specific extension's limitations, and once that extension improved, I switched back to a regular workspace since everything was under one directory anyway.

Related questions (that won't help you, but may give a tiny bit more insight):

- [Is it possible to have multiple projects in a single VS Code workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75835225/11107541)
- [Monorepo - Multiple .vscode settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72808674/11107541)